# Puppet6 getting error: "does not have a Release file."

Tags: apt, repository, apt-mirror, puppet, debmirror

I am getting the famous error message when fetching puppet6 repo from an internal webserver hosting our ubuntu repositories.

```
E: The repository 'http://ubunturepo.office.tho.com/apt.puppetlabs.com focal Release' does not have a Release file.
```

Even though the `Release` file is already there.

Here is the config file for `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
deb  http://ubunturepo.office.tho.com/apt.puppetlabs.com focal puppet6
```

Here is the directory:

```
root@ubunturepo:/var/spool/apt-mirror/skel/apt.puppetlabs.com/dists/focal# ll
total 212
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root  4096 Jan 10 14:06 ./
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root  4096 Dec 23 14:29 ../
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 99083 Dec 16 21:18 InRelease
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root  4096 Dec 23 16:07 puppet6/
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 98215 Dec 16 21:18 Release
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   819 Dec 16 21:18 Release.gpg
```

```
[om:root@test ~]# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I fix a 404 Error when using a PPA or updating my package lists?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65911/how-can-i-fix-a-404-error-when-using-a-ppa-or-updating-my-package-lists)

Comment: No this is a totally different issue

Answer (score 2):

If you try the repository's URL in a browser, you get redirected to a domain name service company's website. So it looks like the domain isn't set up properly (yet), has been suspended or is not reachable for some other reason. And on the domain name service company's website, there surely isn't a `Release` file ;)

Comment: `tho` is just an alias for the company name because it has to be confidential.

Comment: Omar, the point being made in this answer is **the website doesn't exist** ergo there's no such repository. So, just remove the non-existing PPA.

Comment: the website does exist internally. This points out to a webserver hosting our repos.

Comment: @OmarAbdelrazik if it exists internally then it's not properly configured for Focal as a release.  That's something you have to take up internally with the team managing this, there's nothing *you* yourself can do to fix it.  Additionally, if this is an apt proxy then it needs to be set up AS an apt proxy, which this doesn't necessarily seem like it's set up as properly.

Comment: I am supposed to configure Focal as a release but I am new to this so maybe I missed something. In the Focal dist, the Release file exist and in sources.list (on the client side) I am pointing out to it. Is there something I am doing wrong here or missing?